# Installing an uptodate version of Mono on Ubuntu using docker

Tags: ubuntu, mono, docker

This has been really really painful so far! I just want to get a recent build of Mono into my Ubuntu docker container! It seems the Ubuntu distro is ridiculously out of date and I need to get a recent build on so that I can run a ServiceStack API from it.

Here is my docker file:

```
#DOCKER-VERSION 0.9.1

FROM    ubuntu:14.04

ADD     . /src
RUN     cd src
RUN     sudo bash
RUN     apt-get -y install git
RUN     apt-get -y install autoconf
RUN     apt-get -y install libtool
RUN     apt-get -y install g++
RUN     apt-get -y install gettext
RUN     apt-get -y install make
RUN     apt-get -y install mono-complete
RUN     git clone git://github.com/mono/mono.git /home/mono
RUN     cd /home/mono
RUN     ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
RUN     make
RUN     make install

CMD     ["mono", "/build/Web.Api.exe"]
```

Rather than building from source I have also tried:

```
#DOCKER-VERSION 0.9.1

FROM    ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER wayneo

ADD     . /src

RUN     sudo bash
RUN     apt-get update
RUN     apt-get -f install
RUN     apt-get -y -q install wget
RUN     wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/tpokorra:/mono/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key -O- | apt-key add -
RUN     apt-get remove -y --auto-remove wget
RUN     sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/tpokorra:/mono/xUbuntu_14.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-opt.list"
RUN     apt-get -q update
RUN     apt-get -y -q install mono-opt

CMD     ["/opt/mono/bin/mono", "/src/build/Web.Api.exe"]
```

Which also does not work!

Has anyone managed to do this? Surely it should be easier than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things here which seem a bit "odd" to me.

First of all, you `RUN` a `sudo bash` (to change user you should use the `USER` instruction). From the start of your container you will have root access so you do not need to do this.

On each `RUN` command you will spawn a new container for that layer, I recommend you make all your `apt-get` commands one line like so (although this is not too important):

```
RUN apt-get -y install git autoconf libtool g++ gettext make mono-complete
```

(as you're running `apt-get install` from a non interactive environment, I recommend you also set `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive` so you don't get any prompts.)

It's likely that with your Ubuntu version the apt sources will be out of date. Just to make sure you can download all your packages correctly I recommend before you do this you run an update before `apt-get install`.

```
RUN apt-get update
```

As mentioned above, each "layer" of the Dockerfile creates a new container, so using `cd` in `RUN` wont work. You should use the `WORKDIR` instruction instead to have:

```
WORKDIR /home/mono
```

Each step may produce an error when you run `docker build`. You should check the output when you build.

With all this in mind I have managed to build mono from Git and it seems to execute. The Dockerfile to get to this point is below (I have taken out your `ADD` and `CMD`, be sure to add them). I recommend you check out the Dockerfile reference at https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/.

Once you have built the container, you can go into bash (at least with the Ubuntu base) by running `docker run -t -i <IMAGE ID> /bin/bash`. The image ID will be shown as `Successfully built <ID HERE>`. From here you can debug why your image isn't working correctly.

Lastly it may be worth building `FROM` an existing image which has Mono installed. If you wanted to build from https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/thaiphan/mono/ for example, you'd do

```
FROM thaiphan/mono
```

Rather than `ubuntu`. You can then also `ADD` your own files and add your own `CMD`.

Dockerfile I made from yours with Mono:

```
FROM    ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install git autoconf libtool g++ gettext make mono-complete

RUN git clone git://github.com/mono/mono.git /home/mono
WORKDIR /home/mono
RUN ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
RUN make && make install
```